# When would my application need to run with privileges?

Tags: permissions, security

One way of making sure an application is less prone to attack is to make sure it runs with the least privileges required (user mode preferred).

I've only usually programmed for Windows using the `.NET framework`, but have been toying with web app development using Go recently. I'm new to Ubuntu (and Linux in general), so I'm wondering what I need to do to make sure my server application uses the lowest privilege possible?

I assume not allowing my program to write to system folders is one way, but what are the others?

Comment: Bc. my answer got heavily downvoted, some questions to clarify. (1) You tagged with "user-mode-linux" Do you mean the virtualization technique, that runs linux kernels in userspace (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux)? Bc. That's what the tag is refering to. (2) How do you deploy your web app. Do you run it in an application server, or webserver like Apache or is it standalone? (3) will you deploy in a productive environment, or respectively develop for that (e.g., writing a daemon with init-script etc.), or just for fun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing and folder outside your home will need some elevated privileges, so it's better to keep all of your files inside your home.

```
$ ls -l /~$ ls -l /
total 152
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 May 28 08:29 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 May 26 09:54 boot
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 May  5 10:22 build
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr  8  2014 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4540 May 27 12:35 dev
drwxr-xr-x 208 root root 12288 May 28 08:29 etc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Dec 23 09:43 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Apr  8  2014 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
drwxr-xr-x  28 root root  4096 May 22 08:38 lib
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root 12288 May  7 13:20 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 14 08:28 lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    36 Feb 25 14:00 libnss3.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Dec 23 09:43 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 May 13 18:17 media
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Dec 23 09:43 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4096 May  8 08:05 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 308 root root     0 May 26 13:35 proc
drwx------  23 root root  4096 May 20 08:53 root
drwxr-xr-x  32 root root  1200 May 28 08:29 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 May 28 08:29 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar  5  2012 selinux
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr  7  2014 srv
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root     0 May 26 13:35 sys
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Dec 23 09:43 timeshift
drwxrwxrwt  22 root root 24576 May 29 13:52 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Jun 20  2014 usr
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4096 May 22 12:52 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Apr  8  2014 vmlinuz ->
```

As you see all of these directories is owned by root and though to work with these you need some more permissions, unless your home which is represented by `~` and can be accessed from `/home/username` this is the only place for your playground as a normal user.

Comment: I think this answer doesn't give sound advice. It's basically "run in your home dir for safety". But it depends on the user the process is running as and if you want a proper deployment, i.e., a server, then giving internet users access to your homedir is not optimal. Access permissions for servers have been discussed at length and there is an excellent canonical answer at serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, since this is about Ubuntu but your question is a genral Unix/Linux programming question.
Anyway, here it goes:

1. Learn about Unix/Linux permissions

You saying "(user mode preferred)" makes me think that you might mix up things. "User mode" vs. "Kernel mode" is a concept of operating system programming. This goes down to CPU privileges, where after a context switch to kernel mode some kernel routines do their job. They can see additional CPU registers and have access to privileged CPU instructions. That is where your Kernel and drivers operate and unless you become a kernel/driver dev, you will never ever have access to that.

All the regular stuff happens in user mode.

There you have "root", the super user with elevated privileges and "regular" users. Additionally a user can be member of multiple groups with different privileges.

See: [An Introduction to Linux Permissions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions) and [Real and Effective IDs](http://www.lst.de/~okir/blackhats/node23.html) or a book about Unix/Linux programming (e.g. "The Art of Unix Programming" by Eric S. Raymond -- I know his "Unix Network Programming", which is a classic)

2. Use no privileges or drop them after use

You're writing a network application? If you want to bind to low numbered ports (< 1024 IMHO), you need root permissions. If you're coding in C, using the regular POSIX API, you can even type "man function" in the terminal (i.e. "man bind"). Should tell you which actions need privileges. Or trial and error. 
It depends on what you want to do. There is lots of stuff where you don't need elevated privileges. So you can start your program as a user, or even create a new user with less group memberships than your default Ubuntu user (which is in "sudoers" etc.).
If you **do** need root privileges, you can drop them after use. E.g. many servers are "setuid root" daemons. They are started with the user ID root, do what they need elevated privileges for and then they call "setuid" to change their user ID (i.e., drop privileges). See [The GNU C Library: Setuid Program Example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setuid-Program-Example.html)

Anyway, I'd recommend a book on the subject. You can also google for "unix security slides", gives some good hits from Unis (the ones from my Uni are unfortunately not publicly accessible).

Comment: I'm curious as to why my answer was downvoted. It's the standard way to deal with this on Unix. Permissions are tied to users and groups. Run your process with the least privileged user possible, if you need privileges drop them ASAP. Most excellent writeup at serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: Another great write-up: https://serversforhackers.com/permissions-and-user-management

Comment: You just got one downvote and 2 upvotes!  ;-)  Some people appreciate your answer...